# saving a new filename in django

Tags: python, django, rename

I have a model in which you can upload an image and the filename will be the field's name:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_file = models.FileField(upload_to='renaming')
```

Renaming works. The image gets the name of title. But now, if the user updates the title, the image filename remains the same and I want to change that:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
        this = Company.objects.get(id=self.id)
        if this.image_file:
            blocks = this.image_file.name.split('.')
            if not blocks[0] == this.name:
                new_name = "%s.%s" % (this.name, blocks[-1])
                this.image_file.name = new_name
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Every time when `someModel` gets saved, it looks if an image exists. If it exists it compares the two strings `name` and `image_file`. If they are not the same `new_name` contains the new name. However, now, I'm not sure how to save that. `new_name.save()` won't work because it's only a string. If I do `self.save()` it will create an infinite loop. I also tried copying and pasting this `super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` again. But it didn't overwrite the filename. 
Is there any way to do this easily without using signals or other functions?

Comment: If this `save()` method belongs to `Company` model, you don't need this line: `Company.objects.get(id=self.id)`. The current object is `self`

Comment: Why would you ever need them to match? The filename stored in the `FileField` is the server's business, not the user's.

Comment: because when I search for the image it needs the same name as the model name

Comment: @Gocht thanks, that optimized my code. any idea of how to save it?

Comment: When you search... the filesystem?

Comment: I recommend you [signals, pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) to avoid save loop.

Comment: @Gocht ok so there is no other way?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes, in my app the user can search for the name of the model and gets an image displayed

Comment: Well, I can't say there's no other way, but that's my suggestion.

Comment: But the app can simply have a view that takes the model name and returns the image data. There's no need for the user to see the actual filename.

Comment: But, i have to say, if a user search based in the model object, you have a `image_file` which does not mind about file name, it's already associated, as @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said: _it's servers business_

Comment: that is true but if he looks in the admin site and see name 'XYZ' with an image_file 'ABC.png' that's really confusing

Comment: Well, why should final user look into the **_admin_** site?

Comment: because the user is an admin?!

Comment: also with a signal and post_save, the post save method gets called everytime when something is saved and not just when something is updated or changed

Answer (score 0):

Use self instead of the this you have (as was pointed out above), do your checks on that, and then call super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs).

Your current way doesn't work because calling super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs) doesn't matter because it's the "this" object which has been changed.

Comment: ok changed it, it also changes the displayed name but it doesn't really  change the filename.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "doesn't really", does it change it or does it still not?

Comment: it changes it in the admin panel but if i click on the link to see the file, i get a dead link. If i check the link with the old file name it works.

Comment: I think you're going to have to run image_file.save() with the new name and the original content per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile before you call super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs).

Comment: ok so I have `self.image_file.save(new_name,content,save=True)` but what do I fill in as content? It's the object's containing the file's content. So I tried `self` and `self.image_file` but it doesn't work it throws an error (unicode object has no attribute reas)

Comment: Per that FieldFile link I put up you have to use an actual file, which I think you should be able to get with
from django.core.files import File
self.image_file.save(new_name, File(self.image_file.open()) (You don't have to pass save=True if you actually want to save).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you change names, it's only changed in the database and not on disc. So I found a solution with `os.rename`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
        if self.image_file:
            blocks = self.image_file.name.split('.')
            if not blocks[0] == self.name:
                new_name = "%s.%s" % (self.name, blocks[-1])
                new_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(self.image_file.path), new_name)
                os.rename(self.image_file.path, new_path)
                self.image_file.name = new_name
                self.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
```